# LUA: Loop in 2d table to display first key name

Tags: lua

Currently I'm stuck on this:
`t = {['79402d'] = {'-5.4','5','1.6'}, ['5813g1'] = {'3','0.15','18'}}`
Now i need to loop through this table to check `if name == t[1]`, but how can i do so?
I tried doing something like: `for i=1,#t,1 do print(t[i])` but it doesn't seem to work.
I hope you can help me guys ;)

Comment: What you want is to check if the key is equal to `'79402d'`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it didn't worked first time but i solved my problem with:
`for a,b in pairs(t) do
print(a, b[1], b[2], b[3])
end`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the length operator # will give you the correct number of elements in a table only in a special case. in your case `#t` will return 0, hence your for loop does nothing.

Please refer to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html **Section 3.4.7 – The Length Operator** for details on how to use the lenght operator.

For a regular array, with non-nil values from 1 to a given n, its length is exactly that n, the index of its last value. so #t will be zero if you have no t[1] or n-1 if t[n] is the first nil value in your table starting from t[1].

As you have no t[1] but only a t['79402d'] and a t['5813g1'] your for loop indexing t[i] would not work anyway.

Please read **3.4.9 – Table Constructors** on how table construction works.
`t = {"hello", "world"}`
 is the same as

```
t = {}
t[1] = "hello" 
t[2] = "world"
```

(here `t[1]` is `"hello"` and `#t` is `2`

whereas `t = {['key1'] = "hello", ['key2'] = "world"}`

equals

```
t = {}
t['key1'] = "hello"
t['key2'] = "world"
```

so `t[1]` here is `nil` and `#t` is `0`

Answer (score 0):

[`#` operator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5) returns lenght of array part of the table. Your table is not an array (i.e. a table with non-nil values from index 1 to a given n). Because of that your loop is not iterating any elements.

Use [`pairs`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pairs) to iterate over all keys in the table regardless of what they are.